# UITableViewDataSource wants smth

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I wrote the code for tableView in Xcode 8 beta and then tried to do it in actual Xcode 7. My code below looks correct except UITableViewDataSource issue. Compilers says:

> Type 'SettingsVC' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

It's strange, 'cos I think that I have implemented all required methods.

```
class SettingsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var chooseTable: UITableView!

    var tableArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        chooseTable.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(tableArray[indexPath.item], forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

P.S. in Xcode 8 everything works great. The same problems I see in 4 others ViewControllers where I use tables.

Comment: did you check the signatures of the functions you're trying to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 7 doesn't support swift 3.0, and you're using Swift 3.0 methods for `UITableViewDataSource`

Replace:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

With:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

Cheers